# Email signature alignment issue at MAC

Tags: html, css, macos, email, signature

I created this simple email signature. I SELECT ALL and COPY PASTE in signature part... Its working fine in outlook but in MAC Mail (Version 7.3)... Image goes out of TABLE

```
www.cellsouq.com/xtra/emailsign/email.html
```

Can anyone help me in this. I want to keep logo infront of name/designation (on right side)

regards

Comment: You should put the relevant code in the question, as posting links to unknown destinations is not the preferred way of presenting code around here.

Comment: I posted complete code there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24624049/email-signature-table-alignment-issue-at-mac-email

Answer (score 0):

Not all mail clients understand colspan="2". Use 2 tables and it will be fine.